# How to use joomla recaptcha plugin to my custom Module?

Tags: joomla

**This Question has been asked earlier also.**
**Best Answer was**
In order to use joomla default recaptcha plugin follow these steps-

1)Get recaptcha keys from http://www.google.com/recaptcha

2)Set these keys to recaptcha plugin and activate it if it's not.

3)Put below code where you want to show recaptcha

```
//php code
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('captcha');
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
$dispatcher->trigger('onInit','dynamic_recaptcha_1');

//html code inside form tag
<div id="dynamic_recaptcha_1"></div>
```

4)Put this code where you validating/processing the form:

```
$post = JRequest::get('post');      
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('captcha');
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
$res = $dispatcher->trigger('onCheckAnswer',$post['recaptcha_response_field']);
if(!$res[0]){
    die('Invalid Captcha');
}
//For Joomla 3.x

$post = JFactory::getApplication->input->post;
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
```

But as i'm new to joomla where do i write these codes?

Comment: Don't use `JRequest` with Joomla 3.x as it's deprecated. Please have a read of the following: http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

Answer (score 0):

3) This has to be in the view where you display the form, mostly in the file com_example/views/form/tmpl/edit.php.

4) This has to be in the controllers save action, mostly in the file com_example/controllers/item.php. Item.php is the file of your object, for example on com_content this file has the name article.php.

Comment: My form is a custom module and there i want to use captcha. Can you help me with that.

Comment: Who is the receiver of the form when you submit the form in the module? Please update your description of the question with this information.

Comment: i have made a custom action page where i will receive the date when the form is submitted.

Comment: Then you have to add 4 in that action.